# Create Columns Dynamically Hive or PIG

Tags: apache-pig, hiveql

I'm a little new to HiveQL and would greatly appreciate some advice.  Does anyone know of a way in HiveQL to dynamically create new columns based on entries in an existing column?  I have a rough sketch of what I'm trying to do below, (F1, F2, FA, FB, FC are fields.)  I apologize for using the periods as spacers.  I'm still getting the hang of formatting posts in stackoverflow.  If this isn't possible I could use PIG as an alternative.  My end goal is to create a hive table with the results.

Before:

F1...... F2

WQ.... A

ER .....B

JZ ......C

After:

F1... FA ...FB... FC

WQ .1

ER . ..........1

JZ . . .................1

Comment: What are you attempting to do? I can't understand what is going on in the before/after you have posted.

Comment: Do you know ahead of time all the possible values for A/B/C...

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me on this.  No I don't know all the possible values.  As the list of unique values in field F2 grows I would like new fields to be added to the result table or view.